# Is Thread.sleep(1000); something reliable to use?

Tags: java

I know that `Thread.sleep(1000);` can be used to freeze the current thread (for 1 second in the example), but since you need to throw an `Exception` I am wondering if it is safe to use it. I don't want to use it in a program and accidentally cause problems.

Is it "ok" to use `Thread.sleep();` or is there a better way to achieve the same outcome?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> since you need to throw an Exception I am wondering if it is safe to use it.

[Thread#sleep only throws 2 exceptions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep%28long%29):

- `IllegalArgumentException` if the parameter is negative
- `InterruptedException` if the thread gets interrupted

=> if you pass a positive number and the thread doesn't get interrupted there will be no exception.

Unless you call `theThread.interrupt()` from another thread you will be fine.

**EDIT**

It seems you want to create a timer - in that case you would make your life much simpler by using [the built-in mechanisms](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html):

```
Runnable r = new Runnable() {
    public void run() { runYourTaskHere(); }
};
ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(r, 0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Answer (score 17):

As an aside, if you want to sleep and know you won't be using interrupts, a handy way to avoid dealing with the InterruptedExceptions is using Guava's Uninterruptibles, eg

```
Uninterruptibles.sleepUninterruptibly(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

This transparently deals with the InterruptedException if one is thrown in the recommended way (ie resetting the interrupted status) and avoids unsightly try-catch blocks.

Comment: Very useful when trying to simulate hanging code that does not react to interrupts (unlike Thread.sleep or Object.wait)

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what you are trying to do, I have seen `Thread.sleep` used and it is usually used to fix a programming mistake, because people think it resolves race conditions.  `Thread.sleep` has to throw an exception because Java doesn't control the CPU (last I checked), so if the CPU has a bug or even if it doesn't and wakes a thread up early / interrupts it in some way the program (Java) needs a way to terminate itself and propagate a message up the stack.  Further this greatly depends on what you mean by "the same outcome"

Answer (score 0):

It is perfectly safe. InterruptedException  has been provided by JVM so that you can handle it if needed ( suppose you want to do something extra when this thread is interrupted)... It actually doesnt mean that something bad has happened.

Comment: So I can make a loop that updates per Thread.sleep() to make a Timer?

Comment: If you need something to repeat at fixed interval TimerTask is a better alternative.

Comment: I agree with Deepak with the proviso that it's safer to use a scheduled executor service. If there an exception thrown by the TimerTask then the Timer itself becomes non-viable and it will not kickoff the timer task at the next schedule. You would have to create a new task. If a executor service is used, it will still invoke the required runnable or callable the next time round if there was an exception thrown by the runnable/callable.

Answer (score 0):

Since `thread.sleep` Suspends the current thread for a specified time (not kill it). So it's safe to use it.